# Executable jar built with spring-boot gradle-plugin missing dependency

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have an executable JAR that I've built with Spring Boot's Gradle plugin. It has the following dependencies in the build file:

**build.gradle**

```
compile('org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.9.0')
compile('org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.9.0')
compile('org.apache.activemq:activemq-kahadb-store:5.9.0')
compile('org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:1.1')
```

The problem is that after I run 
`./gradlew clean build`
 the created artifact does not contain the `activemq-protobuf` jar, only the other activemq jars:

```
[] jar -tf build/libs/application-0.1.0.jar | grep activemq
lib/activemq-client-5.9.0.jar
lib/activemq-broker-5.9.0.jar
lib/activemq-kahadb-store-5.9.0.jar
lib/activemq-openwire-legacy-5.9.0.jar
```

So when I try to run the jar, I got an Exception that a class from this dependency cannot be found:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.protobuf.Message
```

During the build the dependency gets downloaded and it can be found in my gradle cache, it seems that for some reason Spring Boot's Gradle plugin doesn't include it during the `bootRepackage` task.

This dependency is also there in Eclipse, and the project can be run from there.

Any ideas about why it gets missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Spring Boot. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/489) so that we can investigate. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Answer (score 0):

the following is a quick fix, while the bug is resolved.
try this
in your gradle.build file

```
jar {
baseName = 'gs-accessing-data-rest'
version = '0.1.0'
into('lib') {
    from 'oraDrv'
   }
```

}

where oraDrv is a folder in which you have your custom jars or the missing jars. it is assumed that the oraDrv is relative the build.gradle file location.